# npx rollup -c [!] SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, build, rollupjs

While using rollup, if I use following configuration file

```
export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        file: 'bundle.js',
        format: 'cjs'
    }
};
```

I am getting this error

```
npx rollup -c 

[!] SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

rollup.config.js (1:0)
1: ��{
   ^
```

I don't understand why it is not comprehending es6 syntax, this is the reason we use rollup.

Comment: Looks like the file has BOM characters that need to be removed.

Comment: No there are not any BOM characters

Comment: There's some kind of control characters before `{`